# reinterpret_cast between ponter and different size intgeral type

Tags: c++, casting, implicit-conversion

What actually happens when we do the following:
1)

```
int i = -1; // 32 bit
void *p;
p = reinterpret_cast<void*>(i)
```

on 64 bit architecture, sizeof(void*) == 8

2)

```
long long i; // 64 bit
void *p = (unsigned int)(-1);
i = retinterpret_cast<long long>(p)
```

on 32 bit architecture sizeof(void*) = 4

I generally understand what will be the result, but I want somebody to describe the mechanism in terms of the C++ standard for better understanding.

In the second case the behaviour is like those described in "integral promotions"(4.5) (i will be -1)
for the case "int - unsigned long", so do we generally say that pointers are converted like signed integers?

3)

```
int i = ...;
unsigned long long L = ...;
i = L;
```

What rules apply here?

Answer (score 5):

All conversions between pointers and integral types are
implementation defined.  The only guarantee the standard makes
is that:

> A value of integral type or enumeration type can be explicitly
>   converted to a pointer. A pointer converted to an integer of
>   sufficient size (if any such exists on the implementation) and
>   back to the same pointer type will have its original value

The standard does, however, make the statement (in
a non-normative note) that:

> It is intended to be unsurprising to those who know the
>   addressing structure of the underlying machine.

From a quality of implementation point of view, *if* the machine
has linear addressing, casting an `int` to a pointer should
result in a value that corresponds to the value of the `int`, if
the word (whatever its size) is viewed as an integral type; in
other words, the bit pattern isn't changed.  If the integral
type is smaller, and is negative, it is an open question whether
it should be sign extended, or whether the remaining bits should
be set to 0.  I prefer the second, but I think that both can be
considered "unsurprising".

From a pragmatic point of view: there's a significant amount of
software out there which will occasionally cast a small
non-negative integral value to `void*`, and expects to get it
back with a cast later.  Formally, getting it back requires
converting first to a `intptr_t` (or larger); otherwise the code
shouldn't compile.  But I can't imagine a compiler breaking this
otherwise.  For negative values, on the other hand, I'd feel
significantly less sure.  And I'm not sure how small is small,
either.  (I currently use the technique in one special case for
values less than some 40 or 50.  I works with MSC, g++ and Sun
CC, at least, and I can't imagine it failing on any of the other
mainstream Unix machines I've used in the past.  But I wouldn't
count on it on a 16 bit Intel, or some of the other more exotic
machines I've seen, and certainly not on an embedded system.)

Finally, as for your exact questions: it could vary.  I'd try it
and see, counting on the fact that whatever it does, there's
some code somewhere which counts on it doing that, and that the
vendor won't risk changing the behavior.  Formally, since it is
implementation defined, the implementor is required to document
it (and could, of course, change it in the next version), but
I've generally found it very, very difficult to find this
documentation.

EDIT:

I just noticed that your final question concerned `unsigned long
long` to `int`.  This is an integral conversion, and not
a `reinterpret_cast`, so different rules apply.  Or rather, the
rules are specified in a different section: the basic rule is
still "implementation defined":

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it
>   can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field
>   width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

The C standard is somewhat different here, in that it explicitly
allows an implementation defined signal to be raised.  (It's
stretching it somewhat to say that the "value" in the C++
standard could be the raising of a signal, even if this would be
the preferred implementation.)  In practice: all of the
compilers I know just ignore the extra high order bits.

Comment: do I understand you correctly that if I test on some platform that (probably negative) int is REALLY placed without a change in the 4 lower bytes of pointer (what is in higher does not matter for me) I can expect that it will work that way there but on some other platform it may fail?  The problem is that I need to store unsigned int in a pointer (through reinterpret_cast int -> ptr -> int) and retrieve it back later. We use Qt and when you create QModelIndex() this is the only way provided by the framework to store the internalId value (or just to use pointer)

Comment: @VladimirLenin If you test on some platform with some compiler, yes.  What happens might change from one compiler to the next, however.  A possibly more interesting question is why do you want to know.  If the goal is later to extract the `int`: converting to `intptr_t` first, then to the pointer, and when extracting, first converting to the pointer to `intptr_t`, then to the integral type you want, should work pretty much everywhere, or at least everywhere with linear addressing.

Answer (score -1):

The behavior is Undefined. Anything may happen. It's not even guaranteed that the result is consistent. `reinterpret_cast<void*>(1) == reinterpret_cast<void*>(1)` may be `false`.

Comment: The standard says implementation defined, which means that it's not undefined, and that in fact, the standard must document what it does (although finding this documentation is sometimes difficult).

Comment: @JamesKanze `The standard says implementation defined, which means that it's not undefined` - that's "unspecified", isn't it?

Comment: @ikh The standard says "implementation defined".  That means that the implementation is required to define and specify it, with in the limits given by the standard.  It also guarantees round-trip when starting with a pointer, and using a sufficiently large integral type.  There's nothing undefined here, nor even anything unspecified.

Comment: I disagree with "It's not even guaranteed that the result is consistent    reinterpret_cast<void*>(1) == reinterpret_cast<void*>(1) may be false". If it were true, the roundtrip [pointer 1-> int 2-> pointer] would be not guaranteed on step(2)

Comment: @VladimirLenin In practice, on a machine with linear addressing, yes.  In theory?  What is certain is that there can be cases where `reinterpret_cast<void*>(2) == reinterpret_cast<void*>(3)`; two different `int` can definitely map to the same address.

Comment: @VladimirLenin an integer constant is implicitly int, that is 32 bit even on 64 bit. So, it would be allowed to fill the upper 32 bits of a 64 bit `void*` with random junk -as long as it's dropped when making the opposite conversion!

Comment: @JamesKanze if you had `reinterpret_cast<void*>(2) == reinterpret_cast<void*>(3)`, how could you ever tell them apart? And being able to convert them back is guaranteed. So, no, that cannot happen. The converse in principle can, `reinterpret_cast<void*>(1) != reinterpret_cast<void*>(1)`.